How to connect user with laravel job batch
I'd like to have user's download center in my laravel application
Hence , i need to add the user information for each job batches,
The simplest thoughts in my mind is to add the user_id column on the job_batches table
however it seems that the job_batches table will be updated under the hood by laravel itself when the job dispatched
If using the above approach, i need to "interrupt" the laravel insert process by adding the user_id, but i don't know how to do that
How can I achieve this ? or maybe there is more suitable way to do it rather than interrupting laravel's default process

Why not just add it to the job payload?

@aynber i will try , any good refference to read ?

Not really, other than the official documentation. All of the jobs I dispatch, I usually pass data into the job, so it's easy to add tin that information.

@aynber would you please give the example here ? honsetly i couldn't find the "adding information to payload" on the docs, and even there is a way to do that, i think the retreiving query would be a bit complicated, since the payload data will be stored in JSON

can you give more info on what you are trying to achieve by adding user_id to jobs?

You never showed the code you're using to create and dispatch the job, so I can't tell you how to add it.

@krisgjika to the job_batch table to be exact, in order to make the table view of user's job processes, and also if the job was to download something, i'd like to tell the user the download link if the file is ready, hence each job_bach must be identified by user (initiator)

instead you can create a Process model or whatever, inject that model into each job of this batch, and have each job write to the processes table to update the status

@krisgjika nice idea, sounds less complicated than i thought, thanks for your suggestion

you can fetch user informations from payload of the job, when you dispatch new job send $user in constructor
class YourDownloadJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
 
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct(
        public User $user 
    ) {}
 
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        // Process download here with $user info
    }
}

and when you want to dispatch this job
$user = User::find(1);
YourDownloadJob::dispatch($user)


The goal is to adding the user info (user_id) to the laravel's default job_batch table,
also the user info should be the current user who make the request , so i think request()->user()->id is more relevant here
